# MySQL - Start without limit

Tags: php, mysql, database, limit

I have the following SQL code;

```
    SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 4, 10;
```

I would like the sql to run from result 4 but have no end limit, so I would like the script to get all the results from 4 onwards. Is this possible?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just make the other number impossibly high.  `LIMIT 4, 99999999999`

Comment: If the fourth row can be identified somehow, by its id or timestamp, you can also use the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `OFFSET` option in your query. Like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE id = 1
OFFSET 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 4, 18446744073709551615;
```

resource mysql docs.